# CakePHP disable some radio buttons?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple form with some radio buttons.  I want to disable some of the radio buttons, is this possible?

```
$sixMonths = true;
$twelveMonths = true;
$twentyfourMonths = false;

echo $this->McForm->create('Wizard',  array ('url'=>'/wizard/create'));

$options = array('24' => '24 months','12' => '12 months', '6' => '6 months');
$attributes = array('legend' =>false, 'default' => '6');
echo $this->McForm->radio('period', $options, $attributes);

echo $this->McForm->submit('Save');
echo $this->McForm->end();
```

So in this case I'd like to disable the first radio button and enable the other two.

I know I could probably do it with jQuery, but I'd prefer to do it without using it, is it possible?
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Eric. Would you consider changing your accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible unless you call the `radio` function for each option separately and add `'disabled' => 'disabled'` to the `$attributes` array for the ones you wish to disable. Here's a possible solution:

```
// Options
$options = array('24' => '24 months','12' => '12 months', '6' => '6 months');

// Disabled options
$disabled_options = array('12');

// Default attributes (these may need to be adjusted)
$attributes = array('legend' => false, 'default' => '6');

// Loop through all of the options
foreach ( $options as $key => $value )
{
  // Output the radio button.
  // The field name is now "period.n" which will result in "data[Model][period][n]" where "n" is the number of months.
  // The options is an array contain only the current $key and $value.
  // The 'disabled' => 'disabled' is added to the attributes if the key is found in the $disabled_options array. 
  echo $this->McForm->radio('period.' . $key, array($key => $value), ( in_array($key, $disabled_options) ? $attributes + array('disabled' => 'disabled') : $attributes ));
}
```

Comment: Would it be better to disable/enable using jQuery instead?

Comment: @Eric - That's really up to you. The only thing to consider is that some people may have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Whoever first designed the page relied to much on javascript, so it might not hurt.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

You can add a **`disabled`** array in **`$attributes`** that contains the values ​​of the radios:

```
$attributes = [
    'legend' => false, 
    'default' => '6', 
    'disabled' => ['6', '24']
];
```